# How would you implement setScaleX and setTranslateX for a Drawable similar to implemented for a View?

Tags: android, animation, drawable, android-drawable, objectanimator

I want to use an ObjectAnimator on a custom Drawable (which wraps another inner drawable `toEducate` just to give it these animation capabilities).

I have tried the following, but the animation is not seen as expected.

My implementation is missing anything?

```
  public void setScaleX(float scaleX) {
    Rect bounds = toEducate.copyBounds();
    bounds.right = (int) (bounds.right + scaleX/2);
    bounds.left = (int) (bounds.left - scaleX/2);
    toEducate.setBounds(bounds);
    toEducate.invalidateSelf();
    this.invalidateSelf();
  }

 public void setTranslationX(float translationX) {
    Rect bounds = toEducate.copyBounds();
    bounds.right = (int) (bounds.right + translationX);
    bounds.left = (int) (bounds.left + translationX);
    toEducate.setBounds(bounds);
    toEducate.invalidateSelf();
    this.invalidateSelf();
  }
```

playing this animation:

```
    educationAnimatorSet.playTogether(
        ImmutableList.of(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(educationDrawable, "translationX", 1000).setDuration(2000),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(educationDrawable, "translationY", 1000).setDuration(2000)));
```

and

```
    educationAnimatorSet.playTogether(
        ImmutableList.of(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(educationDrawable, "scaleX", 1000).setDuration(2000),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(educationDrawable, "scaleY", 1000).setDuration(2000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Math in your `setScaleX` method looks wrong because it doesn't increase width `scaleX` times, I mean this lines:

```
public void setScaleX(float scaleX) {
    ...
    bounds.right = (int) (bounds.right + scaleX/2);
    bounds.left = (int) (bounds.left - scaleX/2); 
    ...
}
```

I think method should be something like this (for pivot point in center)

```
    public void setScaleX(float scaleX) {
        int centerX = bounds.left + bounds.width/2;
        int newWidth = bounds.width * scaleX;

        Rect bounds = toEducate.copyBounds();
        bounds.right = centerX + newWidth/2
        bounds.left = centerX - newWidth/2
        toEducate.setBounds(bounds);
        toEducate.invalidateSelf();
        this.invalidateSelf();
    }
```

Also check `getScaleX`, `getScaleY`, `getTranslationX`, `getTranslationY` methods are exist and return proper values. As far as I know getters for custom animated properties should also be provided.

Comment: `Also check getScaleX, getScaleY, getTranslationX, getTranslationY methods are exist and return proper values` they exist to view, I try to implement for a drawable.

Comment: you should declare all these setter and getter methods in your custom drawable class. Because when you call `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(educationDrawable, "scaleX"...)` you say that there is `scaleX` property in `educationDrawable` object class and  `ObjectAnimator` can access/set it via setter and getter of that property (`setScaleX`  and `getScaleX`).